# R cmd check for source package zip file

Tags: r, cmd, package

I created a package with the function ,, create source package'' and as result i got a zip data. How can i run an cmd check for that package in the zip form?

Comment: What are you using to run cmd checks, have you looked into using RStudio?

Comment: If i have a project . On this project i can run a cmd check in r by clicking on the check button .But i dont know how to the the same if i have a package with no project file and just in a zip form